# Should I downvote answers suggesting changes to core files of a CMS?

Tags: discussion

Very often I see questions like this [How To Remove Decimal From Magento-1 Prices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288819/how-to-remove-decimal-from-magento-prices) (most often about wordpress, magento or other CMS)

It is a fact that almost always a change to the core file, although the easiest way to solve a problem, is **unnecessary** and can be avoided by a better solution.

Most likely when you want big changes like that in the question mentioned it involves creating a module, or a plugin and extending those classes there.

This will transform the answer into a rather **complicated** one, most likely it will double it in size and require a lot more time from the answerer. But leaving it like this with loads of votes will give the impression to future readers that this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

Sure. If you think it's a bad idea, feel free to down vote such answers. Consider also leaving a comment with your reasoning (but not necessarily explicitly saying you down voted) or adding a better answer.